# What is "chain structure"?

Tags: mist, blockchain, synchronization

When installing wallet + mist v0.8.3 you see something like this:

[image]

**What is meant by "chain structure"?** Is the "222 of 4446" just a download progress indicator or does each single part have a meaning?

Answer (score 1):

I found the [relevant code](https://github.com/ethereum/mist/blob/c3ae7606ed441f2aad11ed4542fb7ced47ede00e/interface/i18n/mist.en.i18n.json#L139), including:

> `Downloading chain structure __displayState__ of __displayKnownStates__`

This seems to imply that "chain structure" refers to the changes in state of the Ethereum Virtual Machine, with, if I understand correctly, many changes in state per block.